# Play MediaRecorder chunks in MediaSource HTML5 -- video frozen

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc, mediastreamsource

I have this simple code to get chunks of video stream and play them in MediaSource. I see video, but sometimes it stops. It may work for few seconds or for few minutes. But finally it stops at some moment. chrome://media-internals/ shows no errors.

What is wrong here?

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
var constraints = {
    "audio": true,
    "video": {
        "mandatory": {
            "minWidth": 320, "maxWidth": 320,
            "minHeight": 240, "maxHeight": 240
        }, "optional": []
    }
};
window.mediaSource = mediaSource;
var sourceBuffer;
var video = document.querySelector('#video');
window.video = video;
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
    console.log("sourceopen");
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    window.sourceBuffer = sourceBuffer;
}, false);
mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    console.log("error", e)
}, false);
var stack = [];

video.play();
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
    console.log("stream", stream);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
        });
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
    };
    mediaRecorder.start(100);
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

Here is JSFIDDLE which is going to try to do it:
    https://jsfiddle.net/stivyakovenko/fkt89cLu/6/
I am using Chrome as my main target.

Comment: Your example works on my browser
UserAgent:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Its just a question of time. If you wait enough (1-2  minutes, it will get frozen). My chrome is exacty the same.

Comment: I left it for 15+ min, it was fine, also what I noticed is that when I have yours running and I run my code, my code also works [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665469/mediasource-randomly-stops-video?noredirect=1#comment62899304_37665469) , but when I close yours it freezes

Comment: My guess its coincidence. Make enough attempts and mine will also freeze i believe/

Comment: @Steve, I confirm opening this jsfiddle makes my localhost work more stable :))

Comment: yeah, but it stills freezes it for me after 20 min or so

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to display what you are recording? (i mean, you can just display the stream and record it separately at the same time)

Comment: I would use something like this for real time communication through websockets, and I guess his example doesnt include websockets for simplicity atm

Comment: I have run some experiments by using [mediasource](https://github.com/feross/mediasource) , [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) , and ffmpeg to pipe in and out properly fragmented video, I managed to maintain a sort of good delay, but after the 6+min mark it freezes.
However when using fs.createReadStream on an already converted video it doesnt freeze.

Comment: What do you mean by "pipe in and out" ? Do you send back video chunks through sockets / pipe to every client / viewer ? Personnaly I thought about making a stream with the concatened video fragments (a .m3u8 file for example), but I'm stuck with the ffmpeg command...

Comment: Yeah, your approach sounds more scalable

Comment: The freezing on the ffmpeg attempt was caused by node's spawn stderr buffer overflowing and its been resolved, now the only issue that remains is that the stream doesnt seem to be seekable (user cant receive video when entering the room while the stream already started), and for some reason chrome doesnt play the webm stream, only the mp4 one.

Comment: well, chrome team assumes webm file is broken, as far as i am able to understand bug details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Chrome...

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606000

Comment: Seems to be fixed now (I'm the reporter of the bug).

Comment: Change the addSourceBuffer to use "opus,vp9", as that is likely what chrome is using (you can specify it when setting up the MediaRecorder).

Comment: You also need to check for sourceBuffer.updating, and if it's true you need to wait before adding the new data to the sourceBuffer.

Comment: @CpnCrunch comment 81 is deleted

Comment: Adding `opus,vp9` doesn't work with Chrome - tested on `Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: I tried 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus' instead of 'video/webm;codecs=vp9' and that works for me on V81.

Answer (score 1):

The mediarecorder will give you part of a whole webm file in the ondataavailable callback. Look like this kind of stuff is not work with mediaSource. It can not work at all in my chrome 66.

Here is a way that works like "video chat" or "live stream" with MediaRecorder without ffmpeg:

- You can send that data part by part to your sever with ajax.
- The server can return "the whole webm file" to your chrome browser in one 
  long time response. And the server can return more data part in that response as soon as the server some data from the client.

And this kind of workaroud works only with html too:

- You can use a blob list to collect all the blob that come from ondataavailable.
- then set the video.src again and again.

Here is a jsfiddle that works:

```js
const constraints = {video: true};

const video1 = document.querySelector('.real1');
const video2 = document.querySelector('.real2');

var blobList = [];

var gCurrentTime = 0;
function playNew(){
 gCurrentTime = video2.currentTime;
 var thisBlob = new Blob(blobList,{type:"video/webm"});
 var url = URL.createObjectURL(thisBlob);
 video2.src = url;
 video2.currentTime = gCurrentTime;
 video2.play();
}
video2.onended = playNew;

var isFirst = true;
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  video1.srcObject = stream;
  var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,{mimeType:"video/webm"});
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
 blobList.push(e.data);
 if (isFirst){
  playNew();
  isFirst = false;
 }
  }
  mediaRecorder.start(1000);
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error('Reeeejected!', error);
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
  then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

```html
<video class="real1" autoplay controls></video>
<video class="real2" controls></video>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4akkadht/1/

The html only solution (second one) will blink again and again and have a huge delay. The server long push solution (first one) will not blink and have five seconds delay.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience of working with MediaRecorder and MediaSource, most of the errors related to the video freezing or returning errors may be due to the chunks being received out-of-sync. I believe that webm (and maybe other media types also) need the chunks to be received in increasing order of their timecodes. Recording, sending and then receiving the chunks Async may not preserve this increasing order of timecodes.

So, after the above analysis of my own experience of video freezing with MediaRecorder/MediaSource, I changed my code to send the recorded chunks in Sync, not Async.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this as well, however I do not get any video at all. Your jsfiddle does not work for me on chrome or firefox (tested on ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7).

After a bit of research (mainly streaming back the file after it has been recorded), I've found out that the file is not properly fragmented to be played by MSE.
@Steve: I'd be interested to find out how you've done the fragmenting with ffmpeg.

As a sidenote, I also have a similar question here: [Display getUserMediaStream live video with media stream extensions (MSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957007/display-getusermediastream-live-video-with-media-stream-extensions-mse) , with an error description from chrome://media-internals.

Comment: Vasile, if jsfiddle doen't work, may be you should also report this as bug to chrome developers?

Comment: Well the fact that it doesn't work in firefox either makes me think that maybe it isn't a bug. I'll take a look at the mse specification and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Vasilie, chrome team has accepted it as a bug, see another answer.

Comment: It was me who reported the chrome bug, and I can confirm that it works perfectly in firefox. Note that there is a bug in the above code: it doesn't handle the case where the sourcebuffer is busy, so appendBuffer could be failing.

Answer (score 0):

a working example in chrome but it freez in firefox

```
  const main = async(function* main(){
  const logging = true;
  let tasks = Promise.resolve(void 0);

  const devices = yield navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  console.table(devices);

  const stream = yield navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
  if(logging){
    stream.addEventListener("active", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    stream.addEventListener("inactive", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    stream.addEventListener("addtrack", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    stream.addEventListener("removetrack", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
  }

  const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"'});
  if(logging){
    rec.addEventListener("dataavailable", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    rec.addEventListener("pause", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    rec.addEventListener("resume", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    rec.addEventListener("start", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    rec.addEventListener("stop", (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    rec.addEventListener("error", (ev)=>{ console.error(ev.type, ev); });
  }

  const ms = new MediaSource();
  if(logging){
    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    ms.addEventListener('sourceended', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    ms.addEventListener('sourceclose', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    ms.sourceBuffers.addEventListener('addsourcebuffer', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    ms.sourceBuffers.addEventListener('removesourcebuffer', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
  }

  const video = document.createElement("video");
  if(logging){
    video.addEventListener('loadstart', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('progress', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('canplay', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('playing', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('waiting', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('seeking', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('seeked', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('ended', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('emptied', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('stalled', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); }); // annoying
    video.addEventListener('durationchange', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('ratechange', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('play', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('pause', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    video.addEventListener('error', (ev)=>{ console.warn(ev.type, ev); });
  }
  //video.srcObject = ms;
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms);
  video.volume = 0;
  video.controls = true;
  video.autoplay = true;
  document.body.appendChild(video);

  yield new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', ()=> resolve(), {once: true});
  });

  const sb = ms.addSourceBuffer(rec.mimeType);
  if(logging){
    sb.addEventListener('updatestart', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); }); // annoying
    sb.addEventListener('update', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); }); // annoying
    sb.addEventListener('updateend', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); }); // annoying
    sb.addEventListener('error', (ev)=>{ console.error(ev.type, ev); });
    sb.addEventListener('abort', (ev)=>{ console.log(ev.type); });
    }

  const stop = async(function* stop(){
    console.info("stopping");
    if(sb.updating){ sb.abort(); }
    if(ms.readyState === "open"){ ms.endOfStream(); }
    rec.stop();
    stream.getTracks().map((track)=>{ track.stop(); });
    yield video.pause();
    console.info("end");
  });

  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "stop";
  button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.body.removeChild(button);
    tasks = tasks.then(stop);
  }, {once: true});
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  let i = 0;
  rec.ondataavailable = ({data})=>{
    tasks = tasks.then(async(function*(){
        console.group(""+i);

      try{
        if(logging){ console.log("dataavailable", "size:", data.size); }

        if(data.size === 0){
          console.warn("empty recorder data");
          throw new Error("empty recorder data");
        }

        const buf = yield readAsArrayBuffer(data);

        sb.appendBuffer(buf);
        yield new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          sb.addEventListener('updateend', ()=> resolve(), {once: true});
          sb.addEventListener("error", (err)=> reject(ev), {once: true});
        });

                if(logging){
          console.log("timestampOffset", sb.timestampOffset);
          console.log("appendWindowStart", sb.appendWindowStart);
          console.log("appendWindowEnd", sb.appendWindowEnd);
          for(let i=0; i<sb.buffered.length; i++){
            console.log("buffered", i, sb.buffered.start(i), sb.buffered.end(i));
          }
          for(let i=0; i<video.seekable.length; i++){
            console.log("seekable", i, video.seekable.start(i), video.seekable.end(i));
          }
          console.log("webkitAudioDecodedByteCount", video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount);
          console.log("webkitVideoDecodedByteCount", video.webkitVideoDecodedByteCount);
          console.log("webkitDecodedFrameCount", video.webkitDecodedFrameCount);
          console.log("webkitDroppedFrameCount", video.webkitDroppedFrameCount);
        }

        if (video.buffered.length > 1) {
          console.warn("MSE buffered has a gap!");
          throw new Error("MSE buffered has a gap!");
        }
      }catch(err){
          console.error(err);
        yield stop();
        console.groupEnd(""+i); i++;
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }

      console.groupEnd(""+i);
      i++;
    }));
  };

  rec.start(1000);
  console.info("start");
});



function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout((()=>resolve(ms)), ms));
}


function readAsArrayBuffer(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", ()=> resolve(reader.result), {once: true});
    reader.addEventListener("error", (err)=> reject(err.error), {once: true});
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
}


function async(generatorFunc){
  return function (arg) {
    const generator = generatorFunc(arg);
    return next(null);
    function next(arg) {
      const result = generator.next(arg);
      if(result.done){ return result.value; }
      else if(result.value instanceof Promise){ return result.value.then(next); }
      else{ return Promise.resolve(result.value); }
    }
  }
}

console.clear();
main().catch(console.error);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nthyfgvs/

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great in Firefox, no freezing.  It requires jquery, cgi Python3 for the browser client.  It also has two server-side Python3 programs for writing and reading the webcam data as the data is created.

Browser Client:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="300" height="300" controls></video>
    
    <video id="video2" width="300" height="300" controls></video>
    
    
    <script>
    
        var offsetA = 0;

        var res;
        var pos;
        var b = "base64," ;
        var fr = new FileReader();

        
        function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
            
            var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return new Blob([ab], { type: 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, opus"' });
        }
    

        // 1. Create a `MediaSource`
        var mediaSource2 = new MediaSource();

        // 2. Create an object URL from the `MediaSource`
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource2);

        // 3. Set the video's `src` to the object URL
        var video = document.getElementById("video2");
        video.src = url;

        // 4. On the `sourceopen` event, create a `SourceBuffer`
        var sourceBuffer2 = null;



        
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        var constraints = {
            "audio": true,
            "video": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "minWidth": 320, "maxWidth": 320,
                    "minHeight": 240, "maxHeight": 240
                }, "optional": []
            }
        };
        window.mediaSource = mediaSource;
        var sourceBuffer;
        var video = document.querySelector('#video');
        window.video = video;
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
            console.log("sourceopen");
            sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8, opus"');
            window.sourceBuffer = sourceBuffer;
        }, false);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            console.log("error", e)
        }, false);
        var stack = [];

        video.play();





        mediaSource2.addEventListener("sourceopen", function()
        {
            // NOTE: Browsers are VERY picky about the codec being EXACTLY
            // right here. Make sure you know which codecs you're using!
            sourceBuffer2 = mediaSource2.addSourceBuffer("video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, opus\"");
            sourceBuffer2.mode = 'sequence';

            // Make sure to only append one chunk at a time to the SourceBuffer

            
            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) 
            {
                console.log("stream", stream);
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) 
                {
                
                                fr.onload = function(){
                                
                                    res = this.result;
                                    pos = res.search(b);
                                    pos = pos + b.length;
                                    res = res.substring(pos);
                                
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'post_data_webcam.py',
                                        dataType: "html",
                                        data: { chunk:  res },
                                        success: function(data){
                                            //alert(data + ' yes');
                                        },
                                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                            alert('Status: ' + textStatus + '   ' + ' Error: ' + errorThrown); 
                                        }
                                    });
                                    
                                }
                                fr.readAsDataURL(e.data);
                
                
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
                                    var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
                                });
                                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);

                };
                mediaRecorder.start(1000);
            }, function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            });





            var i = setInterval(function() 
            {
                if (mediaSource2.readyState === "open" && sourceBuffer2 && sourceBuffer2.updating === false )
                {
                        if (sourceBuffer.duration > 2){
                            sourceBuffer.remove(0,  sourceBuffer.duration - 2); 
                        }
                        if (sourceBuffer2.duration > 2){
                            sourceBuffer2.remove(0, sourceBuffer2.duration - 2);        
                        }
                
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'get_data_webcam.py',
                            dataType: "html",
                            async: false,
                            data: { offset: offsetA },
                            success: function(data){
                                data = data.trim();

                                if (data != 'base64,') {
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
                                        var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                                        sourceBuffer2.appendBuffer(arr);
                                    });
                                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( b64toBlob(data) );
                                    
                                    offsetA = offsetA + 1;
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert('Status: ' + textStatus + '   ' + ' Error: ' + errorThrown); 
                            }
                        });         
                }
                
            }, 1000);


        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server-side Python3 webcam video writer:  post_data_webcam.py

```
import os
import sys

import cgi
import cgitb

import base64

include_path = '/var/project_path/www'

cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir=f"""{include_path}/tmp_errors""") # include_path is OUTDIR

sys.path.insert(0, include_path)

def enc_print(string='', encoding='utf8'):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(string.encode(encoding) + b'\n')

from html import escape

args = cgi.FieldStorage()

chunk = '' if not args.getvalue( "chunk" ) else escape( args.getvalue( "chunk" ) )


mp4 = 'webcam.mp4'

mp4_text = 'webcam_text.txt'

with open (mp4, 'ab') as f:
    f.write( base64.b64decode(chunk) )

with open (mp4_text, 'a') as f:
    f.write( str(len(chunk)) + ',' + chunk + '\n' )


html = 'success'

enc_print("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8;")
enc_print()        
enc_print(html)
```

Server-side Python3 webcam video reader: get_data_webcam.py

```
import os
import sys

import cgi
import cgitb

import base64

include_path = '/var/project_path/www'

cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir=f"""{include_path}/tmp_errors""") # include_path is OUTDIR

sys.path.insert(0, include_path)

def enc_print(string='', encoding='utf8'):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(string.encode(encoding) + b'\n')

from html import escape

args = cgi.FieldStorage()

offset = '' if not args.getvalue( "offset" ) else escape( args.getvalue( "offset" ) )


mp4_text = 'webcam_text.txt'

data = ''

try:
    with open(mp4_text, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readlines()[int(offset)]
        data = line.split(',')[1].strip()
except:
    pass

enc_print("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8;")
enc_print()        
enc_print('base64,' + data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE!**
This is version 2 that I also created, it will work in Firefox and Chrome, and no freeze.  Please note, I am using the same two server-side Python3 programs for writing and reading the webcam data as the data is created from my previous answer.

Browser Client version 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<video id="video1" width="300" height="300" autoplay controls ></video>
<video id="video2" width="300" height="300" controls></video>


    <script>
        var offsetA = 0;

                                
        function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
            
            var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return new Blob([ab], { type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp8;' });
        }
    

        // 1. Create a `MediaSource`
        var mediaSource2 = new MediaSource();

        // 2. Create an object URL from the `MediaSource`
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource2);

        // 3. Set the video's `src` to the object URL
        var video = document.getElementById("video2");
        video.src = url;

        // 4. On the `sourceopen` event, create a `SourceBuffer`
        var sourceBuffer2 = null;


const constraints = {video: true};

const video1 = document.querySelector('#video1');
const video2 = document.querySelector('#video2');

//var blobList = [];

function handleSuccess(stream) {
    video1.srcObject = stream;
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,{type:"video/webm; codecs=vp8;"});
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
    
                                //blobList.push(e.data);


                                var res;
                                var pos;
                                var b = "base64," ;
                                var fr = new FileReader();
                                fr.onload = function(){
                                
                                    res = this.result;
                                    pos = res.search(b);
                                    pos = pos + b.length;
                                    res = res.substring(pos);
                                
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'post_data_webcam.py',
                                        dataType: "html",
                                        async:false,
                                        data: { chunk:  res },
                                        success: function(data){
                                            //alert(data + ' yes');
                                        },
                                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                            alert('Status: ' + textStatus + '   ' + ' Error: ' + errorThrown); 
                                        }
                                    });
                                    
                                }
                                fr.readAsDataURL(e.data);
    
  }
  mediaRecorder.start(1000);
  
  
        var i = setInterval(function() 
        {
            if (mediaSource2.readyState === "open" && sourceBuffer2 && sourceBuffer2.updating === false )
            {
                    if (sourceBuffer2.duration > 2) {
                        sourceBuffer2.remove(0, sourceBuffer2.duration - 2);        
                    }
            
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'get_data_webcam.py',
                        dataType: "html",
                        async: false,
                        data: { offset: offsetA },
                        success: function(data){
                            data = data.trim();

                            if (data != 'base64,') {
                    
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
                                
                                    sourceBuffer2.appendBuffer( reader.result );
                                });
                                reader.readAsArrayBuffer( b64toBlob(data) );
                                
                                offsetA = offsetA + 1;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Status: ' + textStatus + '   ' + ' Error: ' + errorThrown); 
                        }
                    });         
            }
            
        }, 1000);
        
        video.play();
        
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error('error', error);
}

        mediaSource2.addEventListener("sourceopen", function()
        {
            // NOTE: Browsers are VERY picky about the codec being EXACTLY
            // right here. Make sure you know which codecs you're using!
            
            sourceBuffer2 = mediaSource2.addSourceBuffer("video/webm; codecs=vp8;");
            sourceBuffer2.mode = 'sequence';

            // Make sure to only append one chunk at a time to the SourceBuffer

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
            
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```